# Como consultar dados de duas tabelas que não possuem associação pelo Sequelize

Tags: sql, sequelize-js

Eu tenho uma tabela chamada "Alteracoes" e essa tabela possui uma coluna chamada "id_tabela" que guarda o id de um item em em uma tabela do sistema (pode ser qualquer tabela do sistema) em que foi feita uma alteração. Preciso fazer uma consulta na tabela de material através da tabela de alterações, porém não é possível pois essas duas não possuem associação.

```
select * from "Alteracao" a 
inner join "Material" m on m.id_material = a.id_tabela 
where a.tabela = 'Material' and a.coluna = 'deletedAt'
and m."deletedAt" notnull
order by m."deletedAt" desc;
```

Answer (score -1):

Acredito que uma união `UNION` resolveria o seu problema, já que não existe relação entre as tabelas.
Lembrando que `UNION` elimina as linhas duplicadas da consulta e `UNION ALL` não elimina as duplicidades.